# LESS parent selector chain in list

Tags: less

Can we store the (ampersand) parent selector chain in a list?
Would not that (finally) enable us to get (only) the immediate parent selector?

```
.parentpart(@n) {
  // Actually, shouldn't be "&" as a string but the parent selector chain.
  @part: extract(~"&", @n);
  @{part} {
    color: red;
  }
}

.a {
  .b {
    .parentpart(1);
  }
}
```

For now, this will output

```
.a .b & {
  color: red;
}
```

But I would love this

```
.a {
  color: red;
}
```

(Or, actually, `.b{color:red;}` by passing a `2` if I was able to get the parent selector chain into the extract function …

Comment: In short, no, you can't use `&` anywhere except selector. Also note even if that `@part: extract(~"&", @n);` would work your code above would result in `.a .b .a {}` selector instead (in other words you can't cancel the nesting itself, thus if some code is put under `.a .b` both will have to appear in the result one way or another - that what nesting is about).

Comment: OK, thank you—what I had feared. But, while I have seen the request for a "partial parent" several times, I haven't seen a good argument against it … Stylus does this beautifully IMO, you can even get an arbitrary partial, e.g. the immediate parent: `.a { .b { ^[-1..-1] > .c {color: red} } }`. http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#partial-reference There, unfortunately, I miss being able to just use a class as a mixin …

Comment: There's [#1075](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075). As for "a good arguments against it" - in Less they follow the opposite paradigm: a feature should have "a good arguments *for* it". (And though at #1075 there's agreement to not reject it if implemented, none of who could actually implement it find it valuable enough to do that, yet at least).